# IIS: HTTPRedirect vs. URLRewrite ActionType="Redirect"

Tags: iis

In terms of performance,

Is a URLRewrite ActionType="Redirect" the equivalent of an HTTPRedirect, in that it's still a client side redirect?

Answer (score 0):

IIS: httpredirect tells you immediately this is a server side response.

urlrewrite comes in various flavors, mostly server side reactions.

Client side redirects would be more like javascript performing:
"window.location = newTarget; exit;"